# R formattable: column width and highlighting rows

Tags: r, formattable

I need to produce a table summarising time series data in which an intervention occurs.

I also want to take advantage of formattable's colour options.

I have two problems I'd be grateful for help with.

First, I want to make the intervention somewhat explicit, for example by having a thicker top border in the corresponding row (time period 6).

Second, I'm having trouble with one column due to its  particularly long name. I'd like to have a selection of columns be of consistent width (i.e. col 2:4 from below code). Ideally, the 'a_rather_long_name' column heading would be across multiple lines.

Also, is there a way to have column heading be left aligned but values be centre aligned?

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(time_period = 1:10, 
                  a_rather_long_name = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))


formattable(data, 
            align = c("l", rep("c", NCOL(data) - 1)), 
            digits = 2,
            list(
              `time_period` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(font.weight = "bold")), 
              `b` = color_tile("transparent", "grey"),
              `c` = color_tile("transparent", "grey"),
              `a_rather_long_name` = color_tile("transparent", "pink") ))
```

Sincere thanks for any advice!